# Setting up html preview mode in Webstorm

Tags: html, preview

I have been experiencing problems with html preview in Webstorm 2017.2 The preview keeps trying to open the file using the following:
http://localhost:63342/index.html/?_ijt=ou39u94jhtpams57t4o3l33qbd, which gives the warning of 404 Not Found.
Opening the file using the path (//file:/home/...) works perfectly fine.

Is there any way I can set the default settings so that Webstorm opens the path to the file instead of using localhost?

Thanks,
Marta